# How can i implement role redirection after a successful login in my MEAN stack Application

Tags: node.js, angular

I have developed a MEAN stack application the backend works fine and the frontend but i want to go much further by implementing role based redirection after login i have 5 roles thats is admin, teacher, nurse, sportsman, and janitor i want each of them to access his/her own page after successful login and should use the same login page

I have tried some several solution online but so far nothing has come to help me this is the fifth time am asking this question without a real solution, please help me solve this its my final year project

**here is my routes.ts**

````
```import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { UserComponent } from './user/user.component';
import { SignUpComponent } from './user/sign-up/sign-up.component';
import { SignInComponent } from './user/sign-in/sign-in.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './auth/auth.guard';
import { AdminComponent } from './user/admin/admin.component';
import { AdminSportComponent} from './user/admin-sport/admin-sport.component'
import {  AdminSuaHubComponent } from './user/admin-sua-hub/admin-sua-hub.component';
import { AdminCictComponent } from './user/admin-cict/admin-cict.component';
import { ViewadminsectionsComponent } from './user/viewadminsections/viewadminsections.component'
import { from } from 'rxjs';

export const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'user',component:SignInComponent
    },
    {
        path:'signup', component:SignUpComponent, canActivate:[AuthGuard]
    },
    {
        path:'admin', component:AdminComponent,
         canActivate:[AuthGuard],
         data:{
             roles:['admin']
         }
    },
    {
        path:'viewsectionadmins',
        component:ViewadminsectionsComponent,
        canActivate:[AuthGuard],
        data:{
            roles:['admin']
        }
    },
    {
      path:'admincict',
      component:AdminCictComponent,
      canActivate:[AuthGuard],
      data:{
       roles:['admincict']
      }
    },
    {
     path:'adminsport',
     component:AdminSportComponent,
     canActivate:[AuthGuard],
     data:{
         roles:['adminsport']
     }
    },
    {
   path:'adminsuahub',
   component: AdminSuaHubComponent,
   canActivate:[AuthGuard],
   data:{
       roles:['adminsuahub']
   }
    },
    {
        path: '',component:SignInComponent
    },
    {
        path:'',redirectTo:'/user', pathMatch:'full'
    }
];```
````

**Here is my app.module.ts**

````
```import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import{ FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import{ RouterModule } from '@angular/router'
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http'

//components
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { UserComponent } from './user/user.component';
import { SignUpComponent } from './user/sign-up/sign-up.component';
import { from } from 'rxjs';

//routes
import { appRoutes } from './routes';
import { SignInComponent } from './user/sign-in/sign-in.component';
import { UserService } from './shared/user.service';
import { AuthGuard } from './auth/auth.guard';
import { AuthInterceptor } from './auth/auth.interceptor';
import { AdminComponent } from './user/admin/admin.component';
import { AdminSportComponent } from './user/admin-sport/admin-sport.component';
import { AdminSuaHubComponent } from './user/admin-sua-hub/admin-sua-hub.component';
import { AdminCictComponent } from './user/admin-cict/admin-cict.component';
import { ViewadminsectionsComponent } from './user/viewadminsections/viewadminsections.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    UserComponent,
    SignUpComponent,
    SignInComponent,
    AdminComponent,
    AdminSportComponent,
    AdminSuaHubComponent,
    AdminCictComponent,
    ViewadminsectionsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  providers: [{
    provide:forwardRef(() => {HTTP_INTERCEPTORS}),
    useClass:forwardRef(() =>{ AuthInterceptor}),
    multi:true
  },AuthGuard,UserService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }```
````

**Here is my User.js**

````
``` const mongoose = require('mongoose');
 const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
 const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

 const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
     fullname:{
         type:String,
         required:'Full name cant be empty',
         min:6,
         max:255
     },
     email:{
         type:String,
         required:'Email cant be Empty',
         max:255,
         unique:true
     },
     University:{
         type:String,
         default:"Sokoine University of Agriculture"
     },
     College:{
         type:String,
         required:'College cant be Empty'
     },

     Department:{
         type:String,
         required:'department cant be empty'
     },
     password:{
         type:String,
         required:'pasword cant be empty',
         max :1024,
         minlength: [6,'password must be atlest 6 character long']
     },
     admintype:{
        type:String,
        enum :['HOD','CICT','Sports','SUASAB','Admin']
    },
     date:{
type:Date,
default:Date.now
     },
     saltSecret:String
 });


 //custom validation
userSchema.path('email').validate((val) => {
    emailRegex = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
    return emailRegex.test(val);
},'Invalid E-mail. ');


 //events
 userSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
     bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt)=> {
         bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
             this.password = hash;
             this.saltSecret = salt;
             next();
         });
     });
 });

 //methods
 userSchema.methods.verifyPassword = function(password){
     return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password);
 };

 userSchema.methods.generateJwt = function() {
     return jwt.sign({ _id:this._id},
        process.env.JWT_SECRET,
        {expiresIn:process.env.JWT_EXP});
 }

 module.exports = mongoose.model('User',userSchema)```
````

**Here is my user.controller.js**

````
```const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = mongoose.model('User');
const passport = require('passport');
const _ = require('lodash');


module.exports.register = (req,res, next) => {

    const user = new User();
    user.fullname = req.body.fullname;
    user.email = req.body.email;
    user.College = req.body.College;
    user.Department = req.body.Department;
    user.password = req.body.password;
    user.admintype = req.body.admintype;
    user.save((err, doc) => {
        if(!err) { res.send(doc)}


        else
        {
            if(err.code == 11000)
            res.status(422).send(['Duplicate email Address Found.'])
            else
            return next(err);
        }
    }) 
}

module.exports.authenticate = (req, res, next ) => {
    //calll for passport authentication
    passport.authenticate('local', (err, user, info) => {
        //error form paasport middleware
        if(err) return res.status(400).json(err);
        //registered user
        else if (user) return res.status(200).json({ "token":user.generateJwt() });
        //unknown user or wrong password
        else return res.status(404).json(info);
    })(req, res);
}

module.exports.userProfile = (req, res, next) =>{
    User.findOne({ _id:req._id},
         (err,user) =>{
             if(!user)
             return res.status(404).json({ status: false, message : 'User Record not Found. '});
             else
             return res.status(200).json({  status:true , user : _.pick(user, ['fullname','email','university','College','Department','admintype'])});
         } );


         //get admins


}```
````

**here is my auth.guard.ts**

````
```import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlTree } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { UserService } from '../shared/user.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {



constructor(private userService:UserService,private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot):  boolean  {


if(!this.userService.isloggedIn()){
  this.router.navigateByUrl('/user');
  this.userService.deleteToken();
  return false;
}

    return true;
  }

}```
````

**here is my user.model.ts**

````
```export class User {
    fullname:string;
    email:string;
    university:string;
    College:string;
    Department:string;
    password:string;
  admintype:string;

}```
````

**here is my user.service.ts**

````
```import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from './user.model';
import{ HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import{ environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import { from } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {
  selectedUser: User = {
    fullname:'',
    email:'',
    university:'',
    College:'',
    Department:'',
    password:'',
    admintype:''
  }

  noAuthHeader = { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'NoAuth': 'True'})};

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }


  //http methods
  postUser(user:User)
  {
    return this.http.post(environment.apiBaseUrl+ '/register' ,user)
  }

  login(authCredentials)
  {
    return this.http.post(environment.apiBaseUrl+ '/authenticate',authCredentials,this.noAuthHeader);
  }

  getUserProfile()
  {
    return this.http.get(environment.apiBaseUrl + '/userProfile');
  }


  //helper methods
  setToken(token:string)
  {
    localStorage.setItem('token',token);
  }

  getToken()
  {
    localStorage.getItem('token');
  }

  deleteToken()
  {
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
  }

  getUserPayload(){
    var token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    if(token)
    {
      var userPayload = atob(token.split('.')[1]);
      return JSON.parse(userPayload);
    }
    else
    return null;
  }

  isloggedIn()
  {
    var userPayload = this.getUserPayload();
    if (userPayload)
    {
      return userPayload.exp > Date.now() / 1000;
    }
  }


  getUserRole()
  {

  }

}```
````

**here is my sign-in.component.ts**

````
```import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { UserService } from 'src/app/shared/user.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sign-in',
  templateUrl: './sign-in.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sign-in.component.css']
})
export class SignInComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor( private userService:UserService, private router:Router) { }

  model = {
   email:'',
   password:''
  };

  emailRegex = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/


  serverErrorMessages : string;
  ngOnInit() {
    if(this.userService.isloggedIn())
    {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/admin');
    }
  }


  onSubmit(form :NgForm)
  {
   this.userService.login(form.value).subscribe( 
     res =>{
      this.userService.setToken(res['token']);
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/admin');
   },
   err =>{
     this.serverErrorMessages = err.message;

   });
  }
}```
````

so far i have no errors but am in need of implementing role based redirection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would suggest you to create a field in mongodb schema as admin with boolean value as true or false depending upon the user, add different fields if any other roles exists,

on login check the user admin status and accordingly inform other parts of your application by subscribing the observables in your service file

call the method in your service file on OnInit method of the component and check whether the user is admin or not if not admin hide the things you don't want to show

and to stop a user from going to routes that are meant for admin add a guard which will navigate the user to homepage if he is not an admin by checking the same observable that you created in the service file.

i hope it helps